# Saving untrained keras model breaks training

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I'm learning how to save a keras model. I wrote a python script based on tensorflow tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile( optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn,  metrics=['accuracy'])

#model.save('model_untrained')
#model.save('model_untrained.keras')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)                                                      
model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)
```

The training converges to accuracy better than 97%.

However, if I uncomment the line

```
model.save('model_untrained.keras')
```

the training no longer converges, accuracy stays at around 10% (which is completely random for a digit recognition task).

If I instead uncomment the other line, using new TensorFlow SavedModel format:

```
model.save('model_untrained')
```

the fit doesn't converge either, and I also get a warning:

```
Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
```

which may or may not be related issue (it seems like an unsolved bug: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34369).

Is it for some reason a mistake to try to save untrained model, or is it a bug?

Tensorflow 2.8.0, Python 3.10.4